# Is it ok to have conditional statements in uianimate blocks?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

Is it ok to do the bellow:

```
UIView.animate { if condition {do something} }
```

Will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this cause any problems?

No. An animation block will animate any animatable properties that are set within the block, but it can contain other code, and is not obliged even to perform any actual animation.